# How to tweak large title in order to keep the transition but hide the large title itself?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition, large-title, preferslargetitles

From a UITabbarViewController I have a root view controller CarDetails as in the first image.
This VC can scroll upwards as shown in the second image, with the large title transitioning to regular navigation display, with the title entered, on the top.

I want the initial view not to show the (large) title, while keeping the transitioning so that the title smoothly appears on top.

How would you do that?

[image: Not scrolled]

[image: Once scrolling]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in XCode:

1. Select your navigationController -> navigationbar.
2. On the right side, in the Attributes inspector, change Large
   Title color from `default` to `clear`.

[image: Change Large Title Color]

Comment: Lol: clever hhhh

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift version of @Starsky idea:

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]
```